# get the values from one dictionary and add the values of another dictionary to it

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested-lists

1.I have a dataframe(df1) with ID containing two values(one is a other is b) and occ is a random value assigned to each ID data:

```
ID       occ
[a1, b1]   3
[a2, b2]   1
[a3, b3]   6
[a4, b4]   2
```

I have another dataframe(df2) containing only b value and along with name column:

```
ID   name
b1   b1_d
b8   b8_d
b3   b3_d
b5   b5_d
```

2.**Expected Result**: I want a dataframe which takes the b values along with occ(from df1) which are present in df2, and add their respective name values(from df2).

```
ID  occ  name
b1   3   b1_d
b3   6   b3_d
```

Code I tried:

```
df3 = {k : [df2.get(x,x) for x in v] for k,v in df1.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode the ID column and then merge:

```
df1.explode('ID').merge(df2, on='ID')

   ID  occ  name
0  b1    3  b1_d
1  b3    6  b3_d
```

Comment: This approach is incomplete. OP says he only wants 'b' values. If there were an 'a' in df2 (a1, for instance) it would appear in the output dataframe.

Comment: @Haddock-san No it is not. According to the OP: "I have another dataframe(df2) containing only b value and along with name column." No need to filter anything out since df2 only contains b values.

Comment: Agreed, however this approach still computes 'a' IDs and adds additional processing time to run the script. Depending on the size of the original dataframe, it could become an important factor. It would be up to the OP to decide.

Comment: The result is showing empty as the df1 ID has 'a' values in it too, so its not merging with df2 ID values as they are different.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be creating a new DataFrame (df3) without the 'a' IDs and merging it with df2 on the 'occ' column to get the names (a sort of vlookup for pandas, if you will).

```
df3 = df
df3['ID'] = df3['ID'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df3 = pd.merge(df3, df2, how='inner', on='ID')
```

df3 outputs:

```
    ID  occ name
0   b1  3   b1_d
1   b3  6   b3_d
```

Comment: This would work but my issue is with removing the 'a' values only.
As I am not able to skim the 'a' values as it is string.

Answer (score 0):

if df1 and df2 can be used as dicts:

```
[(f[1], df1[f], df2[f[1]]) for f in df1 if f[1] in df2]

>>> df1 = { ('a1', 'b1'): 3, ('a2', 'b2'): 1, ('a3', 'b3'): 6, ('a4', 'b4'): 2}
>>> df2 = {'b1': 'b1_d', 'b8': 'b8_d', 'b3': 'b3_d', 'b5': 'b5_d'}
>>> [(f[1], df1[f], df2[f[1]]) for f in df1 if f[1] in df2]
[('b1', 3, 'b1_d'), ('b3', 6, 'b3_d')]
>>>
```